# Python discord bot on a raspberry pi with systemd

Tags: raspberry-pi, python-3.6, raspberry-pi3, discord.py

I have a little problem with my discord bot. I have a systemd setup but everytime I start it it gives me an error code 1. ImportError: No module named 'discord'. Although I have discord.py installed.
Error:

```
● bot.service - Discord Bot
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bot.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-11-08 16:39:16 UTC; 8s ago
Process: 3843 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/pi/luigi-bot/bot.py 
(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 3843 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 08 16:39:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Discord Bot.
Nov 08 16:39:16 raspberrypi python3.5[3843]: Traceback (most recent call 
last):
Nov 08 16:39:16 raspberrypi python3.5[3843]:   File "/home/pi/luigi- 
bot/bot.py", line 3, in <module>
Nov 08 16:39:16 raspberrypi python3.5[3843]:     import discord
Nov 08 16:39:16 raspberrypi python3.5[3843]: ImportError: No module named 
'discord'
Nov 08 16:39:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bot.service: Main process exited, 
code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 08 16:39:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bot.service: Unit entered failed 
state.
Nov 08 16:39:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bot.service: Failed with result 
'exit-code'.
```

bot.service File:

```
[Unit]
Description=Discord Bot
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/pi/luigi-bot/bot.py
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Find where you installed it with `pip show discord` and check **Location**. Then make sure that place is on the PYTHONPATH for the user executing the systemd script.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Where did it show it was installed? How did you set the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: It was installed at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages and I tried to set teh PYTHONPATH but I don't really know how to do it. I used a tutorial. I put it in .bashrc.

Comment: But you are running Python 3.5

Comment: Well I installed Python 3.6 but it runs Python 3.5

Comment: Your `ExecStart` explicitly starts Python 3.5